# Handler stopping up main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization

I'm trying to use a handler to allow the ui of the app to load before a processor intensive task is completed. I've tried using `AsyncTask` but that yielded even worse results.

```
public class MyEditView extends AppCompatEditText {
    Handler handler;

    public MyEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public MyEditView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        handler = new Handler();
        //Removing handler.post speeds up the load of the activity significantly
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Interpreters.ENGLISH.init(context); //Load 133911 line txt file
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to see a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do processor intensive tasks off ui thread, this handler posts runnables to the same thread it is created on, which is ui thread according to the code snippet.

Comment: That's what the handler is for, but it's not working

Comment: You probably created the handler on main thread so the runnable is posted to main thread, that's what's going on.